# python. Import module from child dir which import module from child dir

Tags: python, import, module

I have a src directory in my procject which contains some modules:

```
.
|--src
|----files.py
|----script1.py
|----script2.py
|-notebook.ipynb
```

I have a DVC appilication which run these scripts from cmd. The app uses command

```
python src/script1.py
```

The module *script1.py* import the module *files.py*.

```
import files
```

I am trying to test some functions which are contained in *scripy1.py*.

I use jupyter notebook which is in root project directory.

So wheh I import *scripy1.py* from jupyter notebook:

```
from src import script1
```

I get an error

> No module named 'files'

How can I test using some functions from *scripy1.py* and don't crush current approach?

Answer (score 1):

When you are executing python code, in this case in the jupyter notebook, all imports are relative to the folder the main file is in. This means that in `script1.py` you should either use:

```py
from src import files
```

or

```py
import src.files
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep imports in `script.py` relative to it's directory you could use something like:

```py
from . import file2
```

Comment: But in this case when I execute scripy.py by runing

python src/scripy1.py 

I have the another error - *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'*

Comment: if you want to use the functions from `script1.py` both while having `script1.py` as the main file and when having the notebook as the main file you can use relative imports, or import differently depending on whether the  `script1.py` is the main file or not. For relative imports, see the latest edit of my answer!

Comment: Thank you!
```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import files
else:
    from . import files
```